# Minecraft won't launch after changing username and logging in/out multiple times

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I changed my username on Minecraft, and I tried logging out and back in but it won't work. I tried multiple times but I still can't go on any servers.

Comment: There is a config file in minecraft folder that contains username - change it there, or reinstall minecraft. But no idea if that is an issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the email address associated with the account as the log in ID?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that they now prefer you to use the email address for your account and not the username.

This article details which to use: [Do I log in with my email or username?](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1233873?ref=launcher)

> You log in with your email address if you purchased Minecraft after
>   November 2012, or migrated your username to a Mojang account.
>
> You log in with your username if you have an older Minecraft account,
>   and have not yet migrated to the new account format. You can migrate
>   to a Mojang account from the Mojang accounts page.

Comment: While that link may answer the question, your answer would benefit greatly by adding information in the link into your answer and citing it as a source. If the website you linked in your answer ever goes down this answer will not be very helpful.

Comment: @Ramirez, I have updated my answer to include an excerpt from that article. :)

Comment: much better now.